# Interlayer binding energy: how to convert to meV/Å²?

Tags: energy, units

I've noticed that in most papers the interlayer binding energy is given in units of meV/Å². But how do I get these units? Do I divide the interlayer binding energy I get by the area of my unit cell?

Comment: I'm not sure how area of unit cell is relevant here, normally it's just *contact surface area*. Also, it looks like the title asks to convert *something* to meV/Å², what is it, exactly? Or your question is solely the physical meaning of meV/Å²?

Comment: Typography tip: get to know [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key), which allows to almost instantly type a lot of Unicode symbols with a standard US-keyboard. Linux and macOS typically offer this out of the box, for Windows there is [WinCompose](http://wincompose.info/): to insert an Ångström symbol, I type `Meta + o + A` (I assigned `Meta` to the right `Alt` key) and get `Å`. Similar for umlauts `Meta + " + o` → `ö`.

Comment: @andselisk Sorry, I meant the contact surface area I guess. So if I had $\vec{a}$ = (3, 0, 0), $\vec{b}$ = (1, 2, 0) and $\vec{c}$ = (0, 0, 3) for unit cell vectors, the contact surface area would be the area spanned by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, right?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense to me.